ESPAsyncWebServer.h compile error on ESP32 device
i have issue when using ESPAsyncWebServer.h library on ESP32 device. I'm using example program for simple server, when i compile it, the program error show that way
I tried to make multiple web server with asyncronous web server on esp 32

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you using platformio or arduino IDE ?
